# Magento translation issue for multi stores

Tags: magento, translation

I have two stores in Magento and both of them are using there own translate.csv in theme for different language.

for one store the translation is working fine its translate the word "Telephone","test phone translation" correctly everywhere across the site.

The other store it is not translating, I have to use "Mage_Customer::Telephone","test phone translation" for it to translate.

I would appreciate if someone could explain me why its working fine for one store and other one I need to add "Mage_Customer::" before Telephone for it to work. Thanks

Comment: just do a vardump() in core model translate.php to get the data that is translated, don't know why it containing data like "Mage_Customer::Telephone","Mage_Customer::Submit","Mage_Customer::Email" etc.. do a full search for this on my project, its not present at all. How and Why this is added?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check the below settings for store in admin panel:

On the Admin menu, select **System > Configuration**.

In the upper-left corner, select Configuration Scope of the store view to be translated.

On the General configuration page, click to expand the **Locale Options section**. Then, do the following:

- Set **Locale** to the new language for the store view.
- When complete, click the Save button.

Comment: Locale was already set to the new language for the store view.

Comment: just do a vardump() in core model translate.php to get the data that is translated, don't know why it containing data like "Mage_Customer::Telephone","Mage_Customer::Submit","Mage_Customer::Email" etc.. do a full search for this on my project, its not present at all. How and Why this is added?